# External/standalone (not linked into .exe) .res file?

Tags: resource-files

From my experience .res files are only used in the development stage by MSVC and as such are never shipped with a compiled executable (as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, an old game (2003) I'm playing around with stores all its data - images, sound, fonts -  in a single .res file. It was possible to decompile/unpack it easily with 7zip. The question is, is this actually a "standard" resource file as used by MSVC, or did the developers just develop their own format and decided to name it that for whatever reason? How would I go about modifying it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it: it was actually just a zip file, with the extension changed to .res for whatever reason.